# Hibernate not shutting down threads when Tomcat stops

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jersey

Found some similar issues on stackoverflow but none that seem to be exactly my problem or with an answer that works for me. First time working with this, so I'm sure I'm missing something silly...

Running a web app using Jersey and Hibernate inside Tomcat 8. For the moment, I am doing so inside Eclipse.

This is my ServletContextListener:

```
package com.anwinity.projects.chrono.services;

import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ChronoDatabase implements ServletContextListener
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("INIT");
        sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("DESTROY");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        if(sessionFactory == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Session Factory is null");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Closing Session Factory");
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
        //IOUtils.closeQuietly(sessionFactory);

        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while(drivers.hasMoreElements())
        {
            Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
            if(driver.getClass().getClassLoader() == cl)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.printf("Deregistering JDBC driver %s%n", driver);
                    DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
                }
                catch(SQLException ex)
                {
                    System.out.printf("Error deregistering JDBC driver %s%n", driver);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf("Not deregistering JDBC driver %s as it does not belong to this webapp's ClassLoader%n", driver);
            }
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        System.out.println("Building Session Factory");
        try
        {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Session Factory Build Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
DESTROY
Closing Session Factory
Deregistering JDBC driver org.h2.Driver@63485bee
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [chrono] appears to have started a thread named [MVStore background writer nio:C:/Users/Andrew/chrono.mv.db] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:2684)
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 13, 2015 7:49:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.h2.mvstore.MVMap$2]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.entrySet(MVMap.java:865)
    at org.h2.store.LobStorageMap.removeAllForTable(LobStorageMap.java:320)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.removeOrphanedLobs(Database.java:1319)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.close(Database.java:1240)
    at org.h2.engine.DatabaseCloser.run(DatabaseCloser.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1323)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976322/close-sessionfactory-in-hibernate-4-3 has the answer for your question

Comment: Thanks, I already checked that one. The solutions there didn't totally work. FYI, using hibernate v5.0.2. First, method "getConnectionProvider" doesn't exist for "SessionFactoryImplementor", so that solution won't even compile. The other solution (using c3p0) gives a similar error (well, just a warning). It is called "Resource Destroyer" ... is this warning safe to ignore?

WARNING: The web application [chrono] appears to have started a thread named [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: Which version of H2?